# AWS Lambda + AWS Lambda Layer(dependency)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have kept my python code in Lambda. I have kept the dependencies in a lambda layer(in folder named "python")  and then I have attached the layer to respective lambda.

When I am trying to execute the lambda code I am getting this error:

**Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module "lambda_function": libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

I have the lambda_funtion.py file in root dir of Lambda source code.

Help me fix this issue.

When I remove the imports of layer it works file. As soon as I try to import any library files from layer I get above error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the libraries you're trying to import are linked to [musl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musl) (an implementation of the С standard library).

It happens when you build your layer on a Linux distribution which uses musl (most probably, Alpine).

Lambda runtime uses [glibc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glibc) (another implementation of the С standard library), so modules linked with musl won't work in Lambda.

You have to build your layer on a Linux distribution compatible with Lambda runtime (like [Amazon Linux](https://gallery.ecr.aws/amazonlinux/amazonlinux)).

Comment: thanks for your response. I am installing my dependencies in an Alpine based docker image and zipping. This is handled in the CI/CD gitlab jobs . After that we are publishing into an artifactory and then finally pulling the zip to S3 via terraform and then tagging it to the lambda layer.  Can you help with any image which can fix this issue in the CI/CD stage when we are trying to install dependencies.

Comment: @LazyLizzard the image was given to you in the link above: https://gallery.ecr.aws/amazonlinux/amazonlinux You need to use that instead of Alpine.